# problem in linking viewer selection with current editor - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I often get this error **"Operation linking viewer selection with current editor finished with errors"** in Eclipse Galileo.

Once this error pops up no UI events is working in the IDE , i cant even able to close it also. Every time i have to go to task manager to stop the process , after this IDE works fine for some 5 min and again it display the same error as mentioned above.

i don't know what is happening , can you guys please help.

Comment: Have a look at the `.log` file in the workspace. What are the last couple of errors?

Comment: thx for ur comment Tonny... when i increased the PermSize in eclipse.ini the error is gone..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the Eclipse manual](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F):

PermGen is the permanent generation of objects in the VM (Class names, internalized strings, objects that will never get garbage-collected). An easy, if somewhat memory-hungry fix is to enlarge the maximum space for these objects by adding

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

as an argument to the JVM when starting Eclipse. The recommended way to do this is via your eclipse.ini file.

If you are getting OutOfMemoryErrors while running Eclipse, the VM can be told to let the heap grow to a larger amount by passing the -vmargs command to the Eclipse launcher.

```
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Alternatively, you can invoke the Eclipse executable with command-line arguments directly, as in

```
eclipse [normal arguments] -vmargs -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M -Xmx1024M [more VM args]
```

Answer (score 8):

Just switch your Project Explorer to the Flat package presentation in Eclipse. It works :)

see details here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530450#c7

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Thank you. You pointed me in the right direction! In my case this setting made eclipse slow. Going back to flat presentation restored the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Even with recent versions of Eclipse and Flat Package presentation, if you have a lot of large projects loaded this can still be a problem.
I've found however that if you break up your projects into working sets and minimise the amount of projects/tree nodes open by selecting a working set it can really speed up Eclipse and mitigate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem (Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)) and I fixed it by removing all breakpoints.